# Backbone Marionette Hiding Modules

Tags: marionette, backbone-views

I am developing an webapp with the main application having regions.
At first the main region will be started with the LoginModule, containing a LoginView with html template. Now after the successfull Login I want the LoginModule to stop and hide the view and the start a series of new Modules and render those.
So far I can render new Modules in the applications regions but i fail at stopping and hiding the LoginView. What can I do ?

```
MyApp.module("LoginModule", function(LoginModule, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $,_){

LoginModule.startWithParent = true;

//Private Data And Functions
//E.g. var privateVar = "private";


//Public Data And Functions
//E.g. LoginModule.publicVar = "public";

LoginModule.view = new LoginView();

//Initializer & Finalizer
LoginModule.addInitializer(function(){

});

LoginModule.addFinalizer(function(){
    LoginModule.view = null;
});

//Functions
LoginModule.login = function(email, password){
    //Hardcoded Login
    var marius = new User({name: "Marius", surname: "Widmann", password: "password", email: "marius.widmann@gmail.com"});

    if(marius.get('email') === email){
                    //Start the NavBarView in the header region
                     MyApp.header.show(new NavBarView());
/*####################*/        
    //Now here I want to stop the module or lets say hide the LoginView

    /*####################*/
    }else{
        alert('Login failed');
    }
}

});

//Module Subscribers
MyApp.module('LoginModule').on('LoginView:login', function(email, password){
this.login(email, password);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this app https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette, 
understand it if you know marionette somewhat. I am sure it will help.It is have starting and stooping feature sub-modules apps from the main marionette application.

According to me it is highly modular backbone app.